# How to display the error message in console using Nant in Cruisecontrol?

Tags: nant

I wanted to display some error messages in the console of Cruisecontrol using Nant. Please let me know whether any other way is there rather than the  task .

Thanks & Regards,
Priya.R

Answer (score 0):

use this Link:
[Cruise Control Documentation](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#log)

You can specify an log Entry for occuring errors an "merge" the content of that file to build log.

Hope that solves the problem

Edit:
In addition i would recommend you reading this:

[Blog Entry with Example](http://igloocoder.com/archive/2008/01/04/versioning-applications-using-nant-and-cruisecontrol.net.aspx)